# Object variable or With block variable not set error Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, variables, object, block

The problem i'm facing is the fact that i'm trying to use a variable from a form in another form and it gives me the error "Object variable or With block variable not set".
I've already tryed to use the documentation but it's preety f*****-up.

I've tryed this method:

```
Public urlpoza, regizor, film, blabla(0 To 9999)
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
x = Form1.codfilm
Try
    film(x) = TextBox1.Text
    regizor(x) = TextBox2.Text
    blabla(x) = TextBox3.Text
    urlpoza(x) = TextBox4.Text
    Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(film(x))
    Form1.ListBox1.Refresh()

Catch ex As NullReferenceException
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I've tryed to use in form 2 this:

```
Public Shared codfilm As Form1
```

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/uploads/monthly_04_2013/post-625768-136731764705.png

I've tryed to use in form 2 this too:

```
Public urlpoza, regizor, film, blabla(0 To 9999) As String
```

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/uploads/monthly_04_2013/post-625768-136731763757.png

But i still have the same problem...Any ideeas?

Comment: I would start by switching Option Explicit On, then Option Strict On. Then fix the errors you find. If yo still have problems post the new code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I'm not so sure what thoes option change but the error remained the same

Comment: We need to see more code than what you've shown.  I notice that somewhere along the line your code the variables that you define publicly become arrays.  Also, what is `Form1.codfilm`?  Shouldn't you be taking the value from this and parsing it properly (as per Matt's comment) from (possibly) a text value to a numeric value (most likely integer)?

Comment: At the moment i've resolved my problem by using the advice from @MattWilko so ty verry much 2 all for supporting me :)

Comment: @DominicKexel: I did delete my comments, but personally I stand by them - I prefer **not** to have `Option Infer` turned on as it has the potential to cause problems with code readability.  For instance, `Dim x = 2` can be misinterpreted by a green developer to be any of a number of value types.  And, let's face it, the post above is a classic example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `film` as:

```
Public urlpoza, regizor, film, blabla(0 To 9999)
```

But then you try to assign a string to a position in the array:

```
film(x) = TextBox1.Text
```

This can't work. `file` is not an array, it is probably an Object (hence the error message). If Option Explicit and Option Strict are On - this wont compile

Try explicitly declaring your variables instead - something like this instead:

```
Public urlpoza(0 To 9999) As String, regizor(0 To 9999) As String, film(0 To 9999) As String, blabla(0 To 9999) As String
```